Installing new light fixture: unsure of multiple ground wires
Looking to install a new light fixture. From the ceiling there is a black wire, white wire and bare copper wire
From the light there is also a black wire, white wire and bare copper wire
The plate has one green screw which is set up for the bare copper wire from the light so what do I do with the bare copper wire from the ceiling?
Other than that I was going to connect black wire with black wire and white wire with white wire

Ground wires are always connected together, either by wire nuts or with screws in metal(using the metal as a path).
If the ceiling box is metal, then it should have a ground screw also.
If plastic, then you loop one ground around the screw and wire nut both ground wires together.

The black and white likely don't matter. You probably have a switched hot and a neutral. Hook the black to black, and white to white for consistency.
I assume you have a bracket with a ground screw attached to the bracket. The reason they give you that is you might have a metal box that is grounded. If so, hook the light ground to that and you're done.
Most likely you have a non-metal box. If so, hook the ground wire to the ground supplied with the white and black. As long as the metal from the fixture itself is bonded to the ground somewhere you're good.
